# Why do I receive duplicates while updating a node?

Tags: javascript, gun

*Gun 0.8.8, Node.js-to-Node.js, Node.js-to-browser*

Here is a frontend simulation in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sergibondarenko/tktodk62/20/

To do a clean start I deleted local `data.json` and `gun` data from Chrome Local Storage.

Create a node in Node.js

```
const gun = new Gun({peers:['http://localhost:8080/gun', 'http://localhost:8081/gun']});    
const node = gun.get('watcher/f0de26c0-a29f-11e7-8661-154b982951a4');
node.on(function (v, k) {
  console.log('v:', v); 
  console.log('k:', k); 
});
```

Listen in Node.js

```
const node = gun.get('watcher/f0de26c0-a29f-11e7-8661-154b982951a4');
node.get('stats').on(function (v, k) {
  console.log('v:', v);
  console.log('k:', k);
});
```

Get 1 result as expected, good

```
v: { _: { '#': 'j948ewfltvmmHthoESzM', '>': { num: 1508766155692 } },
  num: 0 }
k: stats
```

Also, I have a listener on the browser side

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script src="http://rawgit.com/amark/gun/master/gun.js"></script>
  <body>
    <script>
      var gun = new Gun({peers:['http://localhost:8080/gun', 'http://localhost:8081/gun']});
      var node = gun.get('watcher/f0de26c0-a29f-11e7-8661-154b982951a4');
      node.get('stats').on(function (v, k) {
        console.log('v:', v); 
        console.log('k:', k); 
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And get 1 result on the node creation as expected, good

```
index.html:9 v: {"_":{"#":"j949102jDUdSklGduZh8",">":{"num":1508767186838}},"num":0}
index.html:10 k: stats
```

Then, I update the node

```
const node = gun.get('watcher/f0de26c0-a29f-11e7-8661-154b982951a4');
node.put({
  stats: {
    num: 2
  },
  name: 'trex'
});
```

And **receive duplicated result** on both listeners

Node.js

```
v: { _: { '#': 'j949102jDUdSklGduZh8', '>': { num: 1508769723940 } },
  num: 2 }
k: stats
v: { _: { '#': 'j949102jDUdSklGduZh8', '>': { num: 1508769723940 } },
  num: 2 }
k: stats
```

Browser

```
index.html:9 v: {"_":{"#":"j949102jDUdSklGduZh8",">":{"num":1508769723940}},"num":2}
index.html:10 k: stats
index.html:9 v: {"_":{"#":"j949102jDUdSklGduZh8",">":{"num":1508769723940}},"num":2}
index.html:10 k: stats
```

Why do I receive duplicates?

---

UPDATE

There are duplicates even if there is only one gun peer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, (And I had this question myself not long ago) then it's because Gun assumes it is in a decentralized lattice network. Each node that gets an update, rebroadcasts that update to all the nodes it knows about. Even though Gun is currently centralized through a relay server, it is built to be decentralized. So therefore, when you create a change, you would broadcast it, but right now it just goes through the relay server which broadcasts for you to every node including your own. So if you had a network of three peers, the relay server sends the update to all three (which includes you). Your peer can deduplicate and not rebroadcast the update but the other nodes will rebroadcast it assuming decentralization. So, therefore you would get one update from the server and then another from each other node.

I'm still not quite clear why I get multiple update pings when I'm the only peer.  I believe it has something to do with the server generously broadcasting the change more than once just to add some redundancy to the system.

Comment: Yes, you have duplicates if there are multiple peers https://github.com/amark/gun/wiki/porting-gun. But there are duplicates even if there is only one gun peer. Very strange, I think it is a bug.

Comment: I've heard that if you are using a storage adapter, the storage adapter behaves like a peer and also rebroadcasts the update.

Comment: @trex `.on(cb)` getting called multiple times is always going to be considered "correct" behavior, even if it is the same data. So you should mark this answer as correct. Getting the same data back multiple times can certainly be annoying, so I recommend using `.open(cb)` instead, as it has many other useful features like giving you the entire depth of the document, check it out here: https://github.com/amark/gun/wiki/API#open . In the future, we'll probably try to reduce how noisy `.on(cb)` is, but it is necessary for now.